# Ada: packaging concepts

Tags: packaging, ada

This is a follow up of my earlier post here:

[Ada: Understanding private types and understanding packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398922/ada-understanding-private-types-and-understanding-packaging)

An implementation for the `Rectangular` type was made using one implementation i.e.   `Rectangular_Method_1` and a specification file and a body file were required for this implementation.

If we want to have another implementation `Rectangular_Method_2` available to the user then the main file  `rectangular_Form.ads` can be changed to

```
-- with Rectangular_Method_1;
-- package Rectangular_Form renames Rectangular_Method_1;
with Rectangular_Method_2;
package Rectangular_Form renames Rectangular_Method_2;
```

Questions

1. Is this the right way in software engineering to allow for another implementation in that the test file `test_rectangular_form.adb` remains the same for a different implementation?
2. If we create a second implementation `Rectangular_Method_2`, Is there a need to create a separate specification file in addition to the compulsory new body for this new implementation? There is the need however to provide the same procedures/functions for `Vector_Basis_r`, `Set_Horz`, `Get_Horz` etc in the new implementation so that we can call them in `test_rectangular_form.adb`.

Thanks...

Comment: Q2: Provided you go along with @oenone’s suggestion of using different files and GPRs, you won’t need a different spec provided the whole spec is the same; but of course if you change it in any way, for example to use polar rather than cartesian coordinates in the private record definition, you will have to use a different spec as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you use GNAT, you can use GPR files for the project. In there you can change the filename for specific packages, for example:

```
for Specification (Rectangular_Form) use "Rectangular_Method_1.ads";
for Implementation (Rectangular_Form) use "Rectangular_Method_1.adb";
```

you can even set this depending on an environment variable.

If your spec files all should look the same, you can use a `Rectangular_Form.ads` and only use the Implementation line from above.

An example GPR file could look like this:

```
project Example is

   type Methods is ("normal", "something_else");
   Method : Methods := external ("METHOD", "normal");

   package Naming is
      case Method is
         when "normal" =>
            for Implementation ("Example") use "example_normal.adb";
         when "something_else" =>
            for Implementation ("Example") use "example_something.adb";
      end case;
   end Naming;

end Example;
```

Then, you can use `gnatmake -P example.gpr` to compile it depending on your `METHOD` variable, or using a `-XMETHOD=...` parameter for gnatmake or just use the provided default value.

The `example_*.adb` should all contain the body of the package `Example`, not `Example_Normal`, etc..

Comment: @ oenone Thanks. Could you please expand on the last line? 1 vote up.

Comment: Well, instead of `package body Example_Normal`, as the filename would suggest, you write `package body Example`, as if the file was named `example.adb`.

Comment: @ oenone Could you please rewrite the example GPR in your answer as closely as you can using my methods and my filenames? You can substitute *example_normal.adb* by *Rectangular_Method_1.adb* and *example_something.adb* by *Rectangular_Method_1.adb*. Make any other necessary adjustments. It will make it easier for me to understand. Thanks.

Comment: No, I will not spoonfeed you. If you have problems to understand it, ask concrete questions.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this would be to use tagged types.

```
package Rectangular is
   type Instance is abstract tagged private;

   procedure Vector_Basis_r (A : in Long_Float; D : out Instance);
   procedure Set_Horz (R : in out Instance; H : Long_Float);
   function Get_Horz (R : Instance) return Long_Float;
private
   type instance is tagged null record;
end Rectangular;

with Rectangular;
package Rectangular_Method_1 is
    type Instance is new Rectangular.Instance with private;
    ...
private
    type Instance is new Rectangular.Instance with 
    record
        Horz, Vert: Long_Float;
    end record;
end Rectangular_Method_1;
```

(similar implementation for Rectangular_Method_2).

Then I believe you can write your code that uses it this way:

```
with Rectangular_Method_1;
with Rectangular_Method_2;
...
--  My_Rectangle : Rectangular_Method_1.Instance;
My_Rectangle : Rectangular_Method_2.Instance;

My_Rectangle.Set_Horiz(Whatever_Value);
...
```

In other words, all you'd have to change when switching between the two is the type names. Your client could even get rid of those changes by using a single subtype at the top.

```
subtype Rectangle_Instance is Rectangular_Method_2.Instance;
```

This would also give you the ability to move common code/fields up into the base class (package), which I think is sort of what you were after.

Comment: @ T.E.D. Thanks, A very interesting alternative indeed. I will investigate and come back if I have questions. 1 vote up.

Comment: @ T.E.D Do you put package `Rectangular` in *rectangular.ads* and package `Rectangular_Method_1` in *Rectangular_Method_1.ads* i.e. separately? If yes, then when I compile *Rectangular_Method_1.ads*, it generates the error message: `>>> "Rectangular" is undefined (more references follow`. Thanks

Comment: @yCalleecharan - Rectangular_Method_1 will have to `with` Rectangular. I'll add that to the quasi-code above to make it clearer. There will probably be other little compiler gotchas though.

Comment: @ T.E.D. Thanks. I get the error when compiling `test_rectangular_form` as: My_Rectangle : Rectangular_Method_2.Instance;
        |
        >>> compilation unit expected